# MANIFEST Specification-Version not visible

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, package

I create a jar file and add a manifest including version information.
In a separate test I can retrieve this information well.

"Sometimes" this does not work, however.
I get a package object for a class loaded from that jar file, but this package does not have the version information provided in the manifest.

Is this because the failing test is run in debug from eclipse, or does it happen when the testing code uses the same package as the jar file provides?

jar file:

```
package org.mycomp.test;
public class C { }
```

my test:

```
package org.mycomp.test;  // is this the problem?
class test_C {
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
   org.mycomp.test.C c = Class.forName("org.mycomp.test.C").getInstance();
   // org.mycomp.test.C c = new org.mycomp.test.C();  // same problem
   Package p = c.getClass().getPackage();
   System.out.println (p.getSpecificationVersion()); // null
  }
}
```

Besides the eventual answer "yes, this is the problem", I'd like to get some hints how to eventually avoid this.

Usually it's desirable to have tests in the same package as the tested code, to get access to package-private objects, isn't it ?

Comment: Are you saying that the test succeeds (shows a `Specification-Version`) when run from the command line (with JARs on the classpath) but fails when launched from within Eclipse? If so, the reason is likely that Eclipse does not build a JAR with `MANIFEST.MF` but just puts the raw `.class` files in your `bin` folder onto the classpath.

Comment: @Andreas: No. I,m not saying that. I definitely built and use a jar file in my Eclipse test. Did not run tests outside Eclipse, yet. (I'll give it a try after Easter) Happy holidays and thanks for your comment. For eventual clarification: the tests are not part of the jar.